# Collections Counter not summing total values

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to use the collections.counter method to count the number of values for each key. So as I'm iterating through my db I want it to keep a count of the number of times a value is found. Instead it just prints a value each time it occurs in the DB. This is my code for the function I use:

```
def clusters(tweetLocation):
    cityCount=None
    cities = {"London":[51.50722, -0.12750], "New York":[-74.006605 ,40.714623]}
    for k,v in cities.items():
        if distance.distance(v, tweetLocation).miles < 50:
            cityCount=k
        else:
            pass 
    return cityCount
```

The code for the script:

```
city_counter=[]
while cursor.alive:#cursor reads all relevant values from the DB
    try:
        doc = cursor.next()
        if not doc['coordinates']:         
            placeName = doc['place']['full_name']
            loc = g.geocode(placeName)
            time.sleep(0.15)
            city_counter=Counter([clusters([loc])])                        
        else: 
            places = doc['coordinates']['coordinates']            
            city_counter=Counter([clusters([places])])
    except (ValueError, geocoders.google.GQueryError):
        pass
    except StopIteration:
        break
print city_counter
```

So rather that returning something like:

```
Counter({New York: 25, London: 15})
```

I get:

```
Counter({None: 1})
Counter({None: 1})
Counter({New York: 1})
Counter({None: 1})
......
```

I've never used the collections.counter before, but I thought it would return a sum of the values.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `Counter()` you create a counter object. To add to it, use its `update()` method. It looks like you probably want to create a Counter object stored in `city_counter`, and then in your loop call `city_counter.update([clusters([loc])])`

See [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for more information

Comment: Thanks....for suggesting the update() method. I'll take a further look at the documentation  to.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're creating a new `Counter` each time, so you're getting a new one returned each time.  You have three options here:

#### Get all the values at once, then create `Counter`

Basically, this would involve you getting the entire list of cities at once and then shoving it through a `Counter`.

```
cities = []
while cursor.alive:
    try:
       cities.append(cursor.next())
    except StopIteration:
       break
print collections.Counter(cities.keys())
```

#### Update `Counter` with each new `doc`

For this, all you have to do is make sure that you have a `Counter` created first, and then use the `update` method.

```
city_counter = collections.Counter()
while cursor.alive:
     city_counter.update([clusters[places]])
     # etc.
```

#### Use a `defaultdict`

For your situation, this might be the best option.

```
city_counter = collections.defaultdict(int)
while cursor.alive:
    city_counter[clusters[places]] += 1
    # etc.
```

Comment: You're right I'm creating new instances of a counter each time. I've been able to use the update() method. Thanks for your answer.